# Copy System.Windows.Documents.Inline without modifying it

Tags: c#, inline, textblock

I'm trying to copy an `Inline inline;` to a new `Inline tempInline` inorder to construct a `TextBlock textbox = new TextBlock(tempInline);`  like this `tempInline = inline;` but the problem is that when I do that my original `inline` changes/ gets modified.

How can I do that, inline doesnt have a copy or clone method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did this,

```
string text = XamlWriter.Save(inline);
Stream s = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(text));
Inline temp = XamlReader.Load(s) as Inline;
```